# Can I update a particular attribute of a tuple with the same attribute of another tuple of same table? If possible what should be the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, plsql, sql-scripts

Suppose I have a table with 10 records/tuples. Now I want to update an attribute of 6th record with the same attribute of 1st record, 2nd-7th, 3rd-8th, 4th-9th, 5th-10th in a go i.e. without using cursor/loop. Use of any number of temporary table is allowed. What is the strategy to do so?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL (and probably other RDBMSes) let you use self-joins in `UPDATE` statements just as you can in `SELECT` statements:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET attr = t2.attr
FROM tbl t2
WHERE tbl.id = t2.id + 5
AND tbl.id >= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy with an update-with-join but Oracle doesn't do that and the closest substitute can be very tricky to get to work. Here is the easiest way. It involves a subquery to get the new value and a correlated subquery in the `where` clause. It looks complicated but the `set` subquery should be self-explanatory.

The `where` subquery really only has one purpose: it connects the two tables, much as the `on` clause would do if we could do a join. Except that the field used from the main table (the one being updated) *must* be a key field. As it turns out, with the self "join" being performed below, they are both the same field, but it is required.

Add to the `where` clause other restraining criteria, as shown.

```
update  Tuples t1
    set t1.Attr =(
        select  t2.Attr
        from    Tuples  t2
        where   t2.Attr = t1.Attr - 5 )
where   exists(
        select  t2.KeyVal
        from    Tuples  t2
        where   t1.KeyVal = t2.KeyVal)
    and t1.Attr > 5;
```

SqlFiddle is pulling a hissy fit right now so here the data used:

```
create table Tuples(
    KeyVal  int not null primary key,
    Attr    int
);

insert into Tuples
    select  1, 1 from dual union all
    select  2, 2 from dual union all
    select  3, 3 from dual union all
    select  4, 4 from dual union all
    select  5, 5 from dual union all
    select  6, 6 from dual union all
    select  7, 7 from dual union all
    select  8, 8 from dual union all
    select  9, 9 from dual union all
    select  10, 10 from dual;
```

The table starts out looking like this:

```
KEYVAL  ATTR
------  ----
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
     5     5
     6     6
     7     7
     8     8
     9     9
    10    10
```

with this result:

```
KEYVAL  ATTR
------  ----
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
     5     5
     6     1
     7     2
     8     3
     9     4
    10     5
```